# How to combine m2e and e(fx)clipse?

Tags: eclipse, javafx-2, maven-3, m2e

I want to create a new project in Eclipse Kepler using the two plugins e(fx)clipse (for JavaFX 2) and m2e. The goal is, to have a Java FX project that I can build with maven from eclipse and that has the folder structure of maven, but I want to use the Java FX SceneBuilder from within Eclipse.

Both plugins have own project types and create different folder structures, so I have to do some stuff manually to combine them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not difficult to do in eclipse.  The way I did it was as follows:

1) Create the java project/structure first using a maven archetype (I can not remember the specific one, but a generic java one would do).
2) To use the JavaFX functionality of e(fx)clipse, just make sure the JavaFX libraries are included in the Libraries of you Build Path.
3) To use SceneBuilder, make sure that the executable is configured in Window|Preferences|JavaFX screen.

NB: if you are using a java version that has javaFX already in it (e.g. java 8 or a recent java 7 releaase) then you don't need to add a separate JavaFX library in the build path. This was only necessary when JavaFX was not bundled with the rest of the JDK, which is no longer the case.

Good luck.

- chooks

Comment: So far, so good, but the e(fx)clipse plugin usually does more. There is an antfile that one usually should run, which I don't want to do, since that's where I want to use maven. +1 anyways, it brought me closer to the goal

Comment: To be honest, I haven't found the functionality of e(fx)clipse that useful. I am using a Java 8 early release that already has JavaFX in it, so the prepackaged JavaFX library that e(fx)clipse gives isn't useful. I don't mess around with the FXGraph feature, so basically the only thing I use it for is to more easily create FXML files (which is not hard anyway) and to launch Scenebuilder from the IDE (which again, is not hard to do).  I wasn't aware of an ant file, as I started my project with maven as described above and went from there.  Glad that I was able to moderately help.

Comment: I think I'll move the same road as you did and ignore e(fx)clipse for the most parts. Thanx for the help!